# Excel VBA Error 1004 in cell formula replacement

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Note : I'm French, so normally I use french functions (e.g. `SI` for `IF` or `SOMME` for `SUM`) and the default decimals separator is the coma and not the point (e.g. `1,03` for `1.03`)

I have to replace many formulas in an Excel workbook, and all of them have the same template, but I could not use the fast fill-in tool, so I'm trying to make a macro for this.

First, here is how the cell currently looks :

`='C:\...\[file1.xlsx]'sheeta!$XXa$nna - 'C:\...\[file2.xlsx]'sheetb!$XXb$nnb`

So basicely, I want to keep these two addresses (I will name them `ad1` and `ad2`) to make the followig formulas :

`=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(ad1;"."));ISNUMBER(VALUE(ad2;".")));SUM(VALUE(ad1,".");PRODUCT(-1;VALUE(ad2;".")));"NA")`

Which substracts two numbers stored with differents formats, and displays `NA` if at least one of them is not a number.

Here is the macro I wrote :

```
Sub tmp()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim adr1 As String
    Dim adr2 As String
    Dim frm As String

    For Each c In Application.Selection.Cells
        adr1 = Split(Split(c.Formula, "=")(1), "-'")(0)
        adr2 = "'" & Split(Split(c.Formula, "=")(1), "-'")(1)

        frm = "=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & adr1 & ";"".""));ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & adr2 & ";""."")));SUM(VALUE(" & adr1 & ";""."");PRODUCT(-1;VALUE(" & adr2 & ";""."")));""NA"")"

        c.Formula = frm
    Next
End Sub
```

The error occures on the last action `c.Formula = frm`.

I've already checked `frm`'s value, and it is good.

I think there is a synthax error on my formula, but I couldn't find it. Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: replace `";"` with `","`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA accept **only** US format formula. US format use `,` instead `;`

```
        frm = "=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & adr1 & ",""."")),ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & adr2 & ","".""))),SUM(VALUE(" & adr1 & ","".""),PRODUCT(-1,VALUE(" & adr2 & ","".""))),""NA"")"
```

Comment: I did the change and I still have the same issue. Here is the line : 
```VBA 
frm = "=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & adr1 & ",""."")),ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & adr2 & ","".""))),SUM(VALUE(" & adr1 & ","".""),PRODUCT(-1,VALUE(" & adr2 & ","".""))),""NA"")"
```

Comment: pls show result of frm:
        ```frm = frm = "=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & adr1 & ",""."")),ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & adr2 & ","".""))),SUM(VALUE(" & adr1 & ","".""),PRODUCT(-1,VALUE(" & adr2 & ","".""))),""NA"")"
Debug.Print frm
        c.Formula = frm```
I add `Debug.Print frm`

Comment: Here is the value taken by frm : `"=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE('03-2020.xlsx'!$AV$63,".")),ISNUMBER(VALUE('03-2020.xlsx'!$AV$59,"."))),SUM(VALUE('03-2020.xlsx'!$AV$63,"."),PRODUCT(-1,VALUE('03-2020.xlsx'!$AV$59,"."))),"NA")"` (I've opened the specified document to shorten the address)

Comment: looks like good... but `VALUE(" & adr1 & ",""."")` --> [VALUE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2) have only **one** argument

Comment: Okay I got it, I was using the wrong function. I had to use "NUMBERVALUE" and not "VALUE". Thanks a lot !